# Stream Analytics:When using a TUMBLING WINDOW is the start time of the window start based on the earliest time in the stream or start time of the job?

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-stream-analytics

### **Context**

I have been reading documentation on how the TUMBLINGWINDOW function is used along with the TIMSTAMP BY clause and can't seem to find a clear explanation on how the start date of a query which contains a TUMBLING WINDOW and TIMESTAMP BY field is calculated (must have missed it if it is present somewhere).

Here are the links to the documentation which I have been looking at:

- TUMBLING WINDOW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/tumbling-window-azure-stream-analytics
- TIMESTAMP By https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/timestamp-by-azure-stream-analytics

I am quoting below the Time Consideration section in the TUMBLING WINDOW LINK (which is the primary source from which my question has arose)

> ### Time Consideration
>
> "Every window operation outputs event at the end of the window. The windows of Azure Stream Analytics are opened at the window start time and closed at the window end time. For example, if you have a 5 minute window from 12:00 AM to 12:05 AM all events with timestamp greater than 12:00 AM and up to timestamp 12:05 AM inclusive will be included within this window. The output of the window will be a single event based on the aggregate function used with a timestamp equal to the window end time. The timestamp of the output event of the window can be projected in the SELECT statement using the System.Timestamp() property using an alias."

It mentions a 5 minute window however doesn't seem to go into detail about why the 5 minute windows are started at this time and most importantly how this would generalise.

**Note:** I understand that this point might have been out of scope for this documentation but I haven't managed to find a clear explanation of this elsewhere either.

### **Question(s)**

Say I have the following code (copied from docs with small modifications)

```sql
SELECT System.Timestamp() AS WindowEnd, TollId, COUNT(*)  
FROM Input TIMESTAMP BY EntryTime  
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(Duration(day, 1)), TollId
```

- How is the start datetime of the window I create selected/chosen if I have a stream of data?

  - Is it based on the earliest time within the EntryTime (which is what I am selecting as the timestamp by field) from which it then logically forms an initial window to encompass ***or*** is it dependent on when I start my stream job running (creating the windows from the time at which the job has started and after)?
- In the scenario that it is dependent on when I start the stream job what's the best way to make sure I start the window so that it includes all data wanted in the initial (and subsequent) windows (in my scenario aggregations by actual whole days e.g start of 2022-02-22 T00:00:00 to 2022-02-23 T00:00:00) ?

  - Would it be to set the start time to custom and select it to start on the beginning of the day? e.g I set the job to start on 2022-02-22 T00:00:00 that way it will start the window at this time so that the first tumbling window (and subsequent ones) would include whole days of data starting from 2022-02-22 T00:00:00 on a days wise basis.

### **Thoughts**

Up until now I have been on the assumption that whatever field I choose in the TIMESTAMP BY clause (e.g EntryTime in the above code snippet) would define the field on which the window is created and then depending on the TUMBLINGWINDOW function arguments chosen (e.g day wise in the above code snippet) would handle how the chosen timestamp field is "windowed" or sliced.
Stream Analytics would then handle the window creation based on the earliest dates present in the source time field at the time of job starting (e.g even if I start a job at 2022-02-22 T09:00:00 UTC if the data is present for the day 2022-02-21 then then the query would output for that day of data 2022-02-21T00:00:00 UTC to 2022-02-22T00:00:00 UTC since that would have passed by this point and the current window (2022-02-22T00:00:00 to 2022-02-23T00:00:00) would populate once that window is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/windowing-azure-stream-analytics#understanding-windows

> Every window operation outputs event at the end of the window. The windows of Azure Stream Analytics are opened at the window start time and closed at the window end time. For example, if you have a 5 minute window from 12:00 AM to 12:05 AM all events with timestamp greater than 12:00 AM and up to timestamp 12:05 AM inclusive will be included within this window. The output of the window will be a single event based on the aggregate function used with a timestamp equal to the window end time. The timestamp of the output event of the window can be projected in the SELECT statement using the System.Timestamp() property using an alias. ***Every window automatically aligns itself to the zeroth hour. For example, a 5 minute tumbling window will align itself to (12:00-12:05] , (12:05-12:10], ..., and so on.***

If you have historical data that you want to output, you can set a custom query start time either as any point up to the max cache of your streaming source (ususally 7 days) or as at the point the query was last stopped, so you don't lose any data during maintenance windows.

The query, however, will only output data with a timestamp that is after the query start time.

Therefore, imagine that your first data has a timestamp of `2022-02-20 01:23:00` and your second a timestamp of `2022-02-21 15:08:00`.  You start your streaming job as at `2022-02-21 14:00:00`, so your 10 minute windows base themselves on the midnight of the 21st and then progress in 10 minute windows from there.  The query does not output anything until the `15:00 - 15:10` window of the 21st, as this is the first window that is both post your query start time and contains data. In this scenario you can see how the windows work and why your data with the `2022-02-20 01:23:00` timestamp would not be output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Still not sure if this fully answers my question.

I still am not sure what is meant by "automatically aligns itself to the zeroth hours", does that imply that my thoughts are true? Is that the same thing as aligning at the earliest time within the EntryTime field (whatever time that is) and then creating windows which start at the zeroth hour of every day from that automatically?

Comment: Essentially meaning that regardless of when the job starts the query would automatically find the earliest date of the timestamp by field and start the windows from there (starting from the zeroth hour)?

Comment: @nishcs No, assuming I am understanding you.  The easiest way to think about it (regardless of how it actually works under the hood) is that the windows always start at midnight and progress forwards from there.  So if your first data point had a timestamp of `01:13` and you specified a 10 minute window, the windows would start at `00:00 - 00:10` and output nothing, then move to `00:10 - 00:20` and again output nothing, progressing forwards with no output until the `01:10 - 01:20` window was reached, in which your first data point would be output.

Comment: Still don't think this concretely confirms my thoughts or not. I understand the scenario that you have given but my main question is say that I start the stream job (which performs the outputting activity) the day after the datetime of `first data point`. Would the TUMBLING WINDOW acknowledge this difference and still (under the hood) behave as you are mentioning in your post (i.e. creating 10 minute tumbling windows starting at midnight of everyday, starting the the earliest timestamp of the data you have, irrespective of the job start time?)

Comment: @nishcs If your first data has a timestamp of `2022-02-20 01:23:00` but you start your streaming job as at `2022-02-21 15:00:00`, your 10 minute windows will base themselves on the midnight of the 21st, not output anything until the `15:00 - 15:10` window of the 21st (which is the first window that is post your query start time) and therefore not output your data with the `2022-02-20 01:23:00` timestamp.

Comment: @nishcs If you have historical data that you want to output, you can set a custom query start time either as any point up to the max cache of your streaming source (ususally 7 days) or as at the point the query was last stopped, so you don't lose any data during maintenance windows.

Comment: Ok great I think this makes more since now, thanks! Just want to parrot again what you said in my own way, say I take the last example you gave and I "physically set" the stream job at `2022-02-21 15:00:00` on my computer to start at a custom time in the past of `2022-02-20 00:00:00` which is before the time of first data point (as per you example) then the 10 minute windows would start on the midnight of 20th where the first window would be `00:00 - 00:10` since that is the first window post my query time but this would output nothing since no data up until the `01:20 - 01:30` window?

Comment: Let me know if my comment above aligns with what you were saying.

Comment: @nishcs  Essentially, yes.  If you are developing this solution within Visual Studio or VSCode, you can very easily test these scenarios with local test data and different query start times.

Comment: Thanks, I think this now explains how the window concept works. Would you be able to add this example to your answer and then I'll accept? It doesn't seem to allow me to edit your response to add this in (it says "suggested edit queue is full").

Comment: @nishcs Updated and slightly revised for conciseness